# SQL trigger - error with new value

Tags: mysql

I would like to give each user 10 points when creating a post.
The error message from Phpmyadmin helps me also not further.
It is probably due to the "new.users_id", but I don't really know.

I have two tables. The points of a user are stored in the "forum_users" table.
If now a new Post is created, I would like to give the user 10 points.
The posts are stored in the "forum_posts" table.
Users_id is the foreign key of "id" in the forum_users table.

I hope you can help my. Thanks!

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER postPoints AFTER INSERT ON forum_posts
BEGIN
UPDATE forum_users SET forum_users.points = forum_users.points + 10 WHERE forum_users.id = NEW.users_id;
END//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
UPDATE forum_users SET forum_users.points = forum_users.points + 10 WHERE' at line 2

Comment: [Mariadb update on Insert trigger](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/create-trigger-statement/) had different implementation of 'WHERE'